# Asp.net SQL backed sessions

Tags: asp.net

If I have sessions backed by SQL Server and run a command sequence like

```
HttpContext.Current.Session['user']
HttpContext.Current.Session['user']
```

Will this make 2 requests to the session DB table to fetch the value, or does asp.net do anything special with the Session object to prevent multiple DB hits?

Comment: did you try to debug in Visual Studio and have the SQL profiler open to see what happens SQL Server side?

Comment: SQL server express doesnt have SQL Profiler unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely YES.

I have SQL server session state setup and i ran Profiler on it. And could clearly see optimized DB calls.
If fact there are optimizations for getting multiple session items in one shot.

Like the below code will also result in SINGLE optimized set of calls (Note: Its not a plain single DB call to get session item)

```
HttpContext.Current.Session['user']
HttpContext.Current.Session['userTwo']
```

NOTE: Tested in .NET 4

You can implement your own session state provider if you need. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx